# InputStream from Assets folder on Android returning empty

Tags: java, android, io, inputstream, assets

I'm not getting any exceptions, but when I run...

```
InputStream deckFile = context.getAssets().open("cards.txt");
```

Then, deckFile.read() returns -1. The file is in the correct folder, and it is NOT empty.

This should be the easiest thing in the world...

EDIT: The AssetManager is indeed listing "cards.txt" as being there, so that shouldn't be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that my file was too big, and was being compressed because of it's ".txt" extension. By renaming the file to a format that is normally compressed, ".mp3", there was no issue

Comment: haha, I've had the same troble, but I've changet file extension to jpg

Answer (score 10):

try below line of code

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("test.txt");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size]; //declare the size of the byte array with size of the file
is.read(buffer); //read file
is.close(); //close file

// Store text file data in the string variable
    String str_data = new String(buffer);
```

the available method returns the total size of the asset...

Comment: this the size of the file in bytes

Comment: Thanks, but it's not solving my problem. The problem is that InputStream seems to think there's nothing there.

Comment: The buffer size may cause OOM on some devices.