# Write a XmlPullParser object for AttributeSet

Tags: java, android, xml, xmlpullparser

My question is about Android/Java.

How can I build a XmlPullParser object that can be read with the `Xml.asAttributeSet` method?

My main.xml contains among other things:

```
<org.javaforum.input
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Enter your E-Mail"
        />
```

So I want to build a XmlPullParser object that contains the attributes and their values you  see above so that in the end I have an AttributeSet object. How can I do this?

I read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56062808/16627950

But I didn't quite get it. Is it even possible to do something like that? Maybe you can explain that to me...

Comment: Can't do it. Even if you could construct and instantiate your own class that could act as an `XmlPullParser`/`AttributeSet`, it wouldn't do you any good inside your `View`'s constructor, 'cause you can't pass a new instance "back out" from that, and you can't modify the one passed in.

Comment: @Mike M. So only the Android System can build an XmlPullParser that can be read by the Xml.asAttributeSet method?

Comment: @Mike M. I tried to see how it is been done. I took a look at the loadXmlResourceParser method here: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/a175a5b/core/java/android/content/res/Resources.java

Comment: Yep. I don't remember exactly which step is the ultimate roadblock (I think it's when you get down to somehow implementing `XmlBlock`, IIRC), but Android's inflation mechanism relies on XML being pre-compiled into a special binary format, and a good chunk of reading that back involves native code and data structures that are opaque at our level.

Comment: @Mike M. It's fascinating how the system compiles XML or other data. Your short, simple and above all understandable explanation is certainly very helpful for other users who try to do the same as me.