# android itext using assets fonts in Android Studio

Tags: android, fonts, itext

I'm trying to create **Persian** pdf files in my android application using [www.itextpdf.com](http://itextpdf.com) but I get `java.io.IOException arial.ttf` not found as file or resource. Here is the code with the problem.

```
BaseFont font = BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
```

this code is fine in `eclipse`(java project not android) but wont work in Android studio. I don't know how to address the **ttf** file. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is obvious: Android does not have Arial font.
You have to ship the appropriate font for your script (Persian) along with your application and read the font from resources/assets/etc.

See also [How to retrieve a list of available/installed fonts in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532397/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-available-installed-fonts-in-android).

**UPD:**

Once you have your file in assets, grab an `AssetManager` via `getAssets()` and use it to read the bytes from the font. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets) answer might be useful.

Afterwards you are free to create your font like this:

```
BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true, false, bytes, null);
```

Meanwhile, I strongly encourage you to read thoroughly on the licensing of the fonts that are shipped with Windows to determine whether you are able to copy-paste Arial font into your application and then use it like this (I doubt so).

Comment: Yes I know that and I added arial.ttf to  /assets/fonts but I get java.io.IOException the question is how to address that arial.ttf file? In a simple java class in eclipse I add the arial.ttf to src and it works but in android Studio it doesn't.

Comment: Would you please tell me how to read bytes from the font? Can you give me more detailed help? Thanks

Comment: You need the first 5 lines from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515873/2333458) answer.

Comment: Still got the problem here is the code: InputStream is = getAssets().open("/assets/fonts/arial.ttf");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            BaseFont base=BaseFont.createFont("arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true, false, buffer, null);

Comment: have you tested the code? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: SO is not a place where the community writes the code for you. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14515590/2333458), which is by the way one of the links I gave you, it is stated in black and white, that if you put your file `abc.txt` into `assets/abc.txt`, then you should access it as `open("abc.txt")`, not `open("assets/abc.txt")`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look here:

Attribute

```
customAttrs:fontType="free_mono"
```

The TextView

```
<com.seamusdawkins.fontcustom.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/str_text_default"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        customAttrs:fontType="free_mono"
        android:gravity="center"/>
```

See this [link](https://github.com/cleidimarviana/custom-font-textview) for more information.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to address a font file so that I can use it to generate pdf file using iText.