# System.IO.IOException: path to ttf file not found as file or resource.'(xamarin.android)

Tags: pdf, xamarin.android, itext7

I'm trying to use custom fonts for my itext7 to allow my pdf to write Arabic texts. what I did is the following:

```
var path2 = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath;
filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(path2.ToString(), "myfile3.pdf");
stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
iText.Layout.Element.Table table = new iText.Layout.Element.Table(3, false);

table.SetWidth(400).SetFixedLayout();
string[] sources = new string[] { "يوم","شهر 2020" };
PdfWriter writer2 = new PdfWriter(stream);
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer2);
Document document2 = new Document(pdfDocument);
PdfFont arab= PdfFontFactory.CreateFont("NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf");
document2.SetFont(arab);
 foreach (string source in sources)
 {    
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        Bidi bidi = new Bidi(source, Bidi.DirectionDefaultLeftToRight);
        if (bidi.BaseLevel != 0)
         {
           paragraph.SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.RIGHT);
             }
                   
         paragraph.Add(source);
 table.AddCell(new Cell(1,1).SetTextAlignment(iText.Layout.Properties.TextAlignment.CENTER).Add(paragraph));
                    }
                    document2.Add(table);
                    document2.Close();
```

I tried different paths for my font. I put it in my resources folder, in my assets, tried to reach it from `C:\Windows\Fonts\ARIAL.TTF` when I tried using arial font, but all of those didn't work, I don't get it, what should my path be so I won't get this exception: System.IO.IOException: path to ttf file not found as file or resource.'

Comment: Please use `File.Exists` to check if the file really exists before feeding that path to iText.

Comment: Could it work now ?

Comment: no sir it still doesn't, I tried file.exists in a console application, it returned true, because my folder is on my pc, but for android app, it returns false

Comment: For android app,did you put the file into the Assets folder ? And use AssetManager to read it .

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your file in assets, you could use `AssetManager` to read the bytes from the font.Then create the font by the bytes.

You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39024559/10768653) and convert it to C# code.

Comment: I tried this:```string content;
 AssetManager assets = this.Assets;
 byte[] bytes =new byte[0];
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(assets.Open("NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf")))
    {
         content = sr.ReadToEnd();
           bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
                }
 PdfFont russian = PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(bytes,false);``` now he's telling me ```itext.io.ioexception: 'type of font is not recognized.' ``` though I downloaded my font from the calligraph documentation

Comment: how do I check?

Comment: You could make a breakpoint on the line which you get the bytes.